# Expandable Table View Cell in Xcode: How can I add text labels for the user to edit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am fairly new to Xcode and Swift, but am trying to create an app. My goal is that I have an Expandable/Collapse TableView. The expandable cell (the subcell of the main cell) will have 2 text fields (one on the right and one on the left) where the user can input information using the keyboard. I am wondering how do I go about inserting 2 text labels and on the expandable cells, and having the user edit these. I am having trouble because I was following along in a video where I was coding most of the elements instead of dragging pieces into my storyboard. I have already created the expandable table view. Thank You!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your question. Show your code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) , where you stuck, and ask a specific question, if you did not find answer by searching for it first! Thanks

Comment: Hi! My question is how do I go about inserting 2 text labels and on the expandable cells, and having the user edit these

Comment: If you want to edit text in a cell then you have to use UITextField instead of UILabel

Comment: Hi Nikhlesh! How would I get the UITextField to only show on the expandable part of the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom table cell or just use cell.contentView.addSubview(YourTextField). Set your two textfield frame position at left and right before addSubview.

```
    let frame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 200, width: 60, height: 40)
    let yourTextField = UITextField(frame: frame)
    cell.contentView.addSubview(yourTextField)
```

Comment: Hi Sherman! Thank You!! This might be a dumb question but where would I put cell.contentView.addSubview(YourTextField), would it be in a method in the ViewController?

Comment: Since you are using a tableview, put it inside                                            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}

Comment: So I added this: let frame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 200, width: 60, height: 40) cell.contentView.frame.addSubView(sub) return cell
But I am still getting an error, saying thst CGRect has no member 'addSubView'

Comment: It's cell.contentView.addSubview(sub), not cell.contentView.frame.addSubview()

Comment: I already edit my answer and add some code so you can follow the example.